# Improve performance for many child components (Quill JS rich-text Eeditor) in Blazor .NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, asp.net-core, blazor

I’m having severe performance problems with Blazor when using multiple instances of the Quill JS editor. I’m interested in why this happens, if this is an inherent limitation in Blazor or is there something I can try to make it faster.

Showing the problem is easy:
I create a new Blazor Server application targeting .NET 5.0. Then go to dependencies and manage the NuGet Packages and add the Blazored.TextEditor which provides the Quill JS richt-text editor. Set up the project according to the documentation (edit _Host.cshtml and _Imports.razor): https://github.com/Blazored/TextEditor

Now edit Index.razor and replace it with:

```
@page "/"
@using Blazored.TextEditor

@for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    <BlazoredTextEditor>
        <ToolbarContent>
            <select class="ql-header">
                <option selected=""></option>
                <option value="1"></option>
                <option value="2"></option>
                <option value="3"></option>
                <option value="4"></option>
                <option value="5"></option>
            </select>
            <span class="ql-formats">
                <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                <button class="ql-strike"></button>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
                <select class="ql-color"></select>
                <select class="ql-background"></select>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
                <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
                <button class="ql-link"></button>
            </span>
        </ToolbarContent>
        <EditorContent>
            contents
        </EditorContent>
    </BlazoredTextEditor>
    <br />
}
```

Start the project, and refresh the page. You can see that individual text boxes take very long to initialize. You can look at the different stages that are visible using the developer tools and then using the “Performance” tab. The problem is, that each QuillJS component takes around 60-70 ms to initialize. I wanted to use a few hundred of these controls, but they are already too slow if only use a handful.

Is there anything that I can do to make this faster? Is this a limitation of Blazor, or is there something in Quill JS that makes it especially bad for this type of use-case?
It seems a lot of time is wasted in manipulating the DOM.

[Image Blazor performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvcGV.png)

If I code the same webpage in plain HTML5, my browser can render everything in the timespan of a single frame. The creation of each Quill control takes around 15-20 ms, so it is much faster.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.3/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</header>
<body>
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
    
<div class="editor1"></div><br />
<div class="editor2"></div><br />
<div class="editor3"></div><br />
<div class="editor4"></div><br />
<div class="editor5"></div><br />
<div class="editor6"></div><br/>

<script>
var config = {
  "theme": "snow"
};

var quill1 = new Quill( ".editor1", config );
var quill2 = new Quill( ".editor2", config );
var quill3 = new Quill( ".editor3", config );
var quill4 = new Quill( ".editor4", config );
var quill5 = new Quill( ".editor5", config );
var quill6 = new Quill( ".editor6", config );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Live playground: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLTU190U7DCX

[Image from performance analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9MpJ.png)
I played a little bit around with the number of toolbar icons, but this only has minimal effect.

(I also tried it by building the Razor child component myself following this tutorial: https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/12, but the result is the same.)